# How to properly format number in denominator with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm discussing fuel efficiency in liters per 100 kilometers (`L/100 km`). My first thought was to do the following:

```
\si[per-mode=symbol]{\liter\per\num{100}\kilo\meter}}
% renders: L/100km
```

However, that omits the space between `100` and `km`. Appending whitespace to the end of `100` has no effect, as I expected. However, adding whitespace outside of `\num` does work:

```
\si[per-mode=symbol]{\liter\per\num{100} \kilo\meter}}
% renders: L/100 km
```

But that seems clunky. Is there a better way? Nothing in the docs is catching my eye:
ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/ctan%3A/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf

Comment: Remove `\num` ? But I think what you want is not standard because then it becomes arithmetic in words I would read it as `L/100`-many  kilometers

Comment: @percusse Exact same situation as with `\num`, unfortunately. I'm open to the idea that this is how you do it, but it seems like there'd be a better way given the depth of the package.

Comment: I get a space with `\liter\per100 \kilo\meter`. Note that num puts the contents in mathmode so spaces are ignored. And lastly I would use `frac` mode with no ambiguity

Comment: @percusse so do I, but that seems equally clunky given how `\SI{>> 5}{\metre}` renders a space between the `5` and `m`

Comment: That's not a unit but the quantity hence the space in between.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways of handling this. You could simple type things in in literal mode, or you could create a new unit to represent '100 km':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\Ckm}{\SI{100}{\km}}
\begin{document}

\si{l/100~km} \si[per-mode = symbol]{\litre\per\Ckm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but why not `\hkm` as hecto-? In my language ckm is a heavy machine-gun. :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Roman numeral representation